# PGP decryption with AWS KMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pgp

I'll do some data import form the third-party. They required me to provide a PGP public key with which they encrypt data. I don't want to generate key pairs on my machine so I'm looking at hosted solution and wondering if we can use AWS KMS (we already use AWS services as infra).

Is it possible to use KMS for that? If not what would be good way to achieve this on AWS?